# Accidentally clicked restore backup instead of backup! Can I still recover my recent photos?

Tags: ios, itunes, backup, photos

I accidentally clicked "restore backup" on iTunes when suddenly all my latest photos were deleted instead my past and deleted photos and videos were restored back and I wasn't able to backup my latest photos.

Can I recover my latest photos?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering lost photos on iPhone 5s after restoring from iTunes backup](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111022/recovering-lost-photos-on-iphone-5s-after-restoring-from-itunes-backup)

Comment: yeah but there's still no answer to my question.

Comment: Let's leave this open since it's not exactly the same intention. That event had two phones - this only one. The answers to both is basically "no - hope you have them on iCloud Photostream or an iCloud Backup or some other service".

Comment: I didn't VTC, it was more of a link to a related question –cc @bmike

Comment: Guess that answers our question @grgarside! Technically his answer's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your photos are probably gone from your phone, but there are a couple other places to check.

Were you backing up to iCloud? If so, you may be able to restore a backup from iCloud to your phone and with it your camera roll. Apple KB article [PH12521](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521).

Were you syncing your photostream to iCloud? If so, fire up iPhoto or the windows iCloud tool and download the photos. Apple KB article [PH13693](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13693).

Comment: Unfortunately my iCloud was disabled. 

Comment: Thank you Todd! :) but I have a question. I read this same problem with mine and it says that before the backup or restore, iTunes will create a backup of the contents in my phone. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Yen, whenever you sync, update or restore your iPhone, the first thing iTunes does is create a backup file. This contains settings, SMS, camera roll etc - pretty much everything except media and apps. You should be able to choose the backup date/time you want to restore from in iTunes if there's a previous backup that will have more of your content.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it comes up pretty high on search results for this topic.

Most of the time, iTunes initiates a secondary backup prior to restoring a backup (presumably for situations just like the question presents.) If you perform an accidental restore:

- Go to the iTunes preferences from the menu. On Mac, Preferences is in the iTunes menu. On Windows, Preferences is in the Edit menu.
- Go to the Devices tab of the Preferences window.
- Look through the backups listed for one with a date appended to the name, with the date of the accidental restore. That is the emergency backup.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I see a backup with my todays date appended, but on the right column it shows me an older date, that is same as the  backup file of accidental restore i performed.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been seeing this as well lately. The "just in case" backup seems to be buggy. Are you on Mac? we can see if the just in case backup did overwrite the old backup or not.